# how to get the rank list of multiple number in a list using C#?

Tags: c#, ranking

I have the following list in C#:

```
List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 1 };
```

I want store their ranks in another list for example `List<double> rank`. Finally I want get the following:

`6  3  5  2  4  1  7`

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by rank? question is unclear and shows no previous attempts...

Comment: I'm guessing the lower the rank the higher the number ?

Comment: @Matias Cicero: the *biggest* number has rank of *1* the second biggest has rank of 2 etc. the lowest item has rank = n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 1 };

var rankDict = arr.Distinct().OrderByDescending(num=>num)
    .Select((number, index) => new {Number = number, Rank = index})
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Number, m => m.Rank);

var rankedArray = new List<double>();

foreach(var num in arr)
{
    rankedArray.Add(rankDict[num] + 1);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", rankedArray));
```

Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/7C5o52

Comment: I used your idea with the following list. But, it is not work because `21` was repeated `List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 21, 1 };`

Comment: @Sawa- Try using a distinct before adding to dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If *all* the items in the arr are *distinct*, you can create a *dictionary*:

```
  List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 1 };

  var ranks = arr
    .OrderByDescending(item => item)
    .Select((item, index) => new {
      item = item,
      rank = index + 1,
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.item, x => x.rank);
```

And then use `ranks` to find out for the item given its corresponding rank:

```
    int rankOf5 = ranks[5]; // 6
```

Test

```
   string test = string.Join(" ", arr.Select(x => ranks[x]));

   // 6  3  5  2  4  1  7
   Console.Write(test);
```

**Edit**: Test with loops:

```
   foreach (var item in arr)
     Console.Write(ranks[item]);
```

Or

```
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; ++i)
      Console.Write(ranks[arr[i]]);
```

**Edit 2** if `arr` *can* have duplicates, e.g.

```
// 21 appears 2 times
List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 21, 1 };
```

you may want to compute so called *dense rank*

```
var ranks = arr
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Key)
  .Select((chunk, index) => new {
     item = chunk.Key,
     rank = index + 1
   })
  .ToDictionary(x => x.item, x => x.rank);

   string test = string.Join(" ", arr.Select(x => ranks[x]));

   // 6 3 5 2 4 1 1 7
   Console.Write(test);
```

Comment: I created loop, but I got error. What is solution

`for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++ )
                Console.WriteLine(ranks[i]);

`

Comment: @Sawa: not `ranks[i]`, but `ranks[arr[i]]`; see my edit

Comment: I used this idea for FCTH approach, but I got the following error 

`An item with the same key has already been added`

what is solution for this error?

Comment: @Sawa: As I've put "..*all* the items in the arr are *distinct*.."; in case you have *duplicates* the first thing you should do is to give a *definition* of the *rank* in that case. There are two popular possibilities: `[1, 1, 10] -> rank(1, 1, 3)` (please, notice hole at `2`) and `[1, 1, 10] -> rank(1, 1, 2)` (so called *dense* rank)

Comment: for the following list is not work because `21` is repeated `List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 21, 1 };` what is solution?

Comment: @Sawa: in case of *dense rank* you can add `GroupBy`, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the shortest way will be to use the `IndexOf` after ordering the list:

```
List<double> arr = new List<double> { 5, 10, 7, 15, 9, 21, 1 };
var ranking = arr.OrderByDescending(item => item)
                 .Select(item => arr.IndexOf(item)+1)
                 .ToList();

//Output: 6, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 7
```

Or just playing with `OrderBy` and `Select`:

```
var ranking = arr.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                 .OrderByDescending(item => item.Item)
                 .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item.Item, OriginalIndex = item.Index, Rank = ++index })
                 .OrderBy(item => item.OriginalIndex)
                 .Select(item => item.Rank)
                 .ToList();

//Output: 6, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 7
```

Comment: that looks like such an overkill XD

Comment: @Neil - The second one? Ya for sure haha, was just playing :)

Comment: I like the first one though. good answer

Comment: @Neil - Thanks :) was just bored so thought about the second - how to get ranking and still keep original order only with selecting and ordering haha